# Defintion for model diversity?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology, ensemble-learning

Two models are diverse if they make prediction errors on different instances. I know there are different measures to quantify diversity, however, I'm looking for formal conceptual definition of what we are trying to measure. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the phrase model diversity. However, it sounds like what you are after is related to the concept of model _sharpness_ in forecasting. A model has _sharpness_ (a.k.a. _resolution, discrimination_) if its predictions are sensitive to differences in the input data. One could construct a measure of distance between two models based on the degree to which they exhibit sharpness on different subregions in the space of input data. One could then derive a measure of diversity as a function of average or aggregate distance between models. Is this sort of what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm referring to the diversity required in an ensemble of classifiers. A requirement of a good ensemble is to have a set of classifiers each of which make prediction errors on different cases in the training set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great book on the topic of ensemble classifier. It is online on:
[Combining Pattern Classifiers](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQFjAA&url=http://www.ccas.ru/voron/download/books/machlearn/kuncheva04combining.pdf&ei=JE3qUIKLGYuRhQectYHICA&usg=AFQjCNFg8OOCimAdTufDpeekdxUG6yLH5g&sig2=0OO_bKEsPL5F2pEP0-UiOA&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.ZG4)

There is a full chapter (ch10) in this book on diversity and how to measure it.

A set of measures are defined in the chapter including:

**1- The Disagreement Measure.**

**2- The Double-Fault Measure.**

**3- The Entropy Measure E.**

4- ...

I hope that this is what you were looking for.

Comment: The cited book is great and thanks for that. However, Ch 10 deals mainly with classification problems. How about regression? My naive approach is to use the old-fashion correlation coef, but I can think of multiple problems with that. Are you aware of anything specific to regression. I can't believe this thread didn't get more views and comments, as this is a very important problem in ML.

Comment: @horaceT One workaround is to discretize the continuous variable and then apply any of those measures by Kucheva. I understand that this is not always meaningful or preserving original level of information. Otherwise, correlation could be a good choice to experiment with or other entropy-based measure for continuous variables.

Comment: This question is prompted by the well known requirement in building ensembles that diversity of the component models gives better performance. Yea entropy should work.